# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity using Azue Table Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, azure-table-storage, .net-core-3.0

I am working in a new aspnetcore 3.0 app in which I am trying to combine Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity authentication and save the data inside the Azure Table Storage. I am having trouble replacing IdentityUser and IdentityRole with my own custom class that inherits the TableEntity class for Azure Table Storage.

Before there where interfaces (IUser, IRole) that can be used alongside the TableEntity class in inheritance to setup the Azure Table Storage. Can someone tell me how to work around this so I can pass my own classes inside services.AddIdentity() method inside my Startup class ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a wrapper which will save and restore values from your own classes. You can do that either by copying properties and creating a mapper, or serialice/deserialize.